# Mongo: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145 after un-commenting and commenting auth=true in mongodb.conf

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mongodb version 2.4.9. I wanted to enable authentication and create users.
So I have un-commented `auth=true` part in mongo conf.(before which I'am supposed to note admin credentials from users collection) When I tried to connect to mongo server using mongo command it says couldn't connect to server which was OK.I realized I didn't made a note of admin credentials so I  commented the same part again and restored conf as before and tried to reconnect again which responds in the same way.

```
couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
```

Can anyone help me about how could I re-connect to server so that I can create my db users.

Comment: Check that mongod is running and you are editing the correct config file. If --auth isn't set, then it won't require authentication even if there are users stored in the `local` database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the auth = true in the mongod.conf and in the mongodb.conf too then reset the server and try again

Comment: There is no file mongod.conf. I can see only mongodb.conf in /etc

Comment: Do you get more information on the error ? and what operating system you use ?

Comment: I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I don't see any other information. I have came across something called **localhost exception** . Do you think it would help?

Comment: Try to run "mongod --noauth" in the Terminal and see what happens